# how to download html table using tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a page which I need to download using tcpdf. Following is the code which I have written but its showing me only a ZERO.

Here is the code which I have written:

```
<?php

require_once('tcpdf.php');


include('simple_html_dom.php');

$filename = '10r6.php';

$ptemplate = file_get_contents($filename);

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('AD');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 002');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

$pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 20);

$pdf->AddPage();

$html = <<<EOD

$ptemplate

EOD;

$pdf->writeHTML(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

$pdf->Output('example_002.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to output html code to the pdf file.

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, true, '');
```

I noticed you used something similar, but you don't seem to have assigned anything to the $html variable. You need to put the whole html code into that variable in order to output it to the pdf file. So, if (I assume) your html code is 'simple_html_dom.php' (which you include on the top of your code), simply do this:

```
$html = include('simple_html_dom.php');
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, true, '');
```

I hope it helps, I actually had hard time yesterday over TCPDF too, but after a whole day I managed to get everything work.

Comment: `$html = include('simple_html_dom.php');` will throw the following error: **TCPDF ERROR:** Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file. Plus, `$html` does have a value - the only issue was the parameters being incorrect.

Comment: Oh, sorry. now I've seen the $html assignment. In any case, the command $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, true, ''); works just well with me.

Comment: I am getting this error after adding $html = include('simple_html_dom.php');
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, true, ''); TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Comment: Check out if your code sends out anything to the page (echo, print_r or similar... or an error) anywhere before the $pdf->writeHTML. If anything (even just a black space) is output before that command, it throws the error you're saying.

Comment: @JoyeetaSinharay See my first comment on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are incorrect.

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, 0, '', '', false, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
```

From [the docs](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1), the parameters are;

```
TCPDF::writeHTML(
    $html,
    $ln = true,
    $fill = false,
    $reseth = false,
    $cell = false,
    $align = '' 
)
```